# Getting wrong results on mysql queries

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp, mariasql

I made a database for an e-commerce mockup.

Every looks fine so far, but when I do some Queries I get wrong results

[I did a sqlfiddle for this so you can look into it](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57cd28/1/0)

When I do

```
SELECT produkt_name, shipping_date 
FROM product, shipping 
WHERE shipping_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```

I expect

| produkt_name | shipping_date |
| --- | --- |
| Ballkleid elegant | 2019-10-22 |
| Cologne Tester Sammlung 1 (10 Flaschen) | 2020-07-11 |
| Glasbläserei Tier: Hase | 2021-12-07 |

But I get this, which is basically every possible product with all existing shipping dates that exist in the database. Including products that were not even sold until 2022.

| produkt_name | shipping_date |
| --- | --- |
| Ballkleid elegant | 2020-07-11 |
| Horus Heresy Collecters Edition | 2020-07-11 |
| Glasbläserei Tier: Hase | 2020-07-11 |
| Ballkleid elegant | 2019-10-22 |
| Horus Heresy Collecters Edition | 2019-10-22 |
| Glasbläserei Tier: Hase | 2019-10-22 |
| Ballkleid elegant | 2021-12-07 |
| Horus Heresy Collecters Edition | 2021-12-07 |
| Glasbläserei Tier: Hase | 2021-12-07 |
| Cologne Tester Sammlung 1 (10 Flaschen) | 2020-07-11 |
| Cologne Tester Sammlung 1 (10 Flaschen) | 2019-10-22 |
| Cologne Tester Sammlung 1 (10 Flaschen) | 2021-12-07 |

Please help me figure out what is wrong.
It might be something with the db design itself, but I cant really figure out where or how.

Comment: The return results are corresponding to the query...
Could you explain what are you trying to get for the result? Why those 3 products only?

Comment: You'll need to join the two tables based on some identifier from what I can figure you'll need to join product, invoice, and shipping to have all the data you'd want for the query.

Comment: I want to get all products that were shipped between those two given dates. Between those 2 dates only these 3 products were shipped.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do more joins than you are doing.
First of all, don´t use than cartesian join because usually runs you to incorrect results. And you need to join with products, orders, invoices and shipping to get your result:

```
SELECT product.produkt_name, shipping.shipping_date
FROM product
join product_order on product_order.fk_produkt_id=product.product_id
join invoice on invoice.fk_order_id=product_order.order_id
join shipping on shipping.fk_invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id
WHERE shipping.shipping_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```

And you can do it in the other way, starting with shippings. It depends on if you have a lot of shippings or not. Both queries return the same result.

```
SELECT product.produkt_name, shipping.shipping_date
from shipping
join invoice  on shipping.fk_invoice_id=invoice.invoice_id
join product_order on invoice.fk_order_id=product_order.order_id
join product on product_order.fk_produkt_id=product.product_id
WHERE shipping.shipping_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
```